# dynamically change viewport maximum-scale 1.0 to 1.5 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I have an orientation problem on iPhone,. I'm using this meta tag in my header

```
<meta id="extViewportMeta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I have a hidden left navigation in my site. When my left navigation is open and tried to change orientation from portrait to landscape then to portrait again, my left navigation is now partially seen.
You can access/view my site here: http://apps.stratpoint.com:9114 for clearer picture.

How to dynamically change viewport maximum-scale? If my orientation is in portrait my maximum-scale has to be 1.0 but when in landscape it has to be in 1.5 value. How can I acheive this in javascript?

This is my code so far:

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    //alert('HOLY ROTATING SCREENS BATMAN:' + window.orientation + " " + screen.width);
    var orientation = window.orientation;

    if(orientation == 0) {
            $('#extViewportMeta').remove();
            $('head').append('<meta id ="extViewportMeta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.5, minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">');
    }else {
            $('#extViewportMeta').remove();
            $('head').append('<meta id ="extViewportMeta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">');
    }
}, false);
```

Problem in my above code is I was able to change my maximum-scale to 1.5 but can't revert it back to 1.0 when in landscape. T_T. Help anyone

Comment: Try removing `initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no` from viewport definition. I use such settings in my page, and iPhone adjusts scale automatically upon orientation change, without any javascript.

Comment: it fixed my issue on iPhone but now tested it in iPad it keeps scaling from portrait to landscape. Even the refresh button doesn't revert it back to its original view. I think I really need to do this in js way. Just can't graps it.

Comment: As another option, try `document.getElementById('extViewportMeta').setAttribute('content','width=' + document.documentElement.scrollWidth);`, that is specify exact width of your content, instead of the "abstract" device-width.